# Check if keyboard and mouse are plugged in with only BusyBox installed

Tags: keyboard, devices, mouse, udev, busybox

Is there a way to detect if a keyboard and a mouse is plugged in (and working) in Linux?

This will be embedded in a PXE setup, so I only have Kernel + Modules and Busybox available.

Bonus question: Is there a way to check if a display is properly connected?

Comment: How about checking for `/dev/input/by-id/*-kbd` and `/dev/input/by-id/*-mouse`? `/sys/devices/virtual/vtconsole/vtcon0/` also appears to be my display.

Comment: What is exactly what you need, an automated test for a runtime script?

Comment: @David Problem is I only have busybox available, so there is no `/dev/input` @Igeorget Yes, this is supposed to be an automated test, notifiying the local admin if a workstation is "broken", i.e. has no mouse/keyboard.